# Node.js Buffer Length

Tags: node.js, express

How do I set the correct length for a buffer in an HTTP response?

I'm using Express.js.  I haven't been able to get this to work:

```
res.set('Content-Length', myBuffer.length);
```

Note, I need to set it manually because I need to send it in the HEAD request.  If I just send the HEAD response without manually setting the Content-Length for what would be the GET request body size, then the Content-Length is set to something small like 2 vs 14000.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  That's exactly what you should be doing.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: In node.js there is a difference between the length in memory and the actual length...won't this only "sometimes" work?

Comment: No, that will always work.  Buffer.length is always the length of the buffer as you see it.  What happens under the hood isn't exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should do the job, but you don't give us any clue about how you get your myBuffer.

Here is an example of code who works, provided there is a text file h:\Temp\text.txt

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile('H:\\Temp\text.txt', function(data, err) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(404, {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            });
            response.write(err);
            response.end();
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
                "Content-Length": data.length
            }
            response.write(data);
            response.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(80);
```

It works because data is a correct Buffer object.
If data is not a Buffer object but a mere string or anything else it could not work. (For example a UTF-8 String can have less characters than its size in bytes).